# A connected set can be discretised by a connected grid

Tags: graph-theory

I have a open, bounded set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. For $h \geq 0$ one can create the following grid: $$\Omega_h = \{ x \in \Omega \mid x=(ih,jh), \quad i,j\in \mathbb{Z} \}.$$

It is claimed that for small enough $h$ the grid $\Omega_h$ is discrete connected, i.e. for each $x,y\in \Omega_h$ there is a path from x to y in $\Omega_h$, if $\Omega$ is connected.

I don't know how to show it, but I had the following Idea:

Consider the grid secquence $\Omega_{h_n}$ with $h_n = 1/2^n$. Then $\Omega_{h_n} \subset \Omega_{h_{n+1}}$. Assume in $\Omega_{h_n}$ are two disconnected points  a,b(no path on grid from a to b).Then, if $\Omega$ is path connected, I find a continuous path from a to b. Using compactness I find a finite sequcene of $\varepsilon$ balls covering the path and lying in the grid. If I choose $h_m < \varepsilon/2$, then these two points are connected in $\Omega_{h_m}$. I'm actually not quite sure if this is true, but even if it true, there might be new points in the grid that are not connected. Either my idea does not work at all or I missed something. Can anyone help?

Comment: The set $\Omega_h$ itself is not connected, it contains only discrete points. Maybe there is a detail missing?

Comment: @daw sorry I ment discrete connected

Comment: What is 'discrete connected'?

Comment: @daw a graph is called discrete connected if any two vertices can be connected by a path. A path is a sequences of vertices which are connected by an edge. Here $\Omega_h$ can be seen as a set of vertex points. 2 points of $\Omega_h$ are connected by an edge if they can be connected by a streight line of lenght $h$ which lies in $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I found a counterexample.

Define
$$
t_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} h_i.
$$
Set
$$
\Omega := \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{\sigma h_n}(t_n,t_n)
$$
with $\sigma \in (\frac23\sqrt2,\ 1)$.

Then $\Omega$ is open (union of open balls) and bounded. The mid-point of the $n$-th ball is in the discrete set $\Omega_{h_n}$. But there is no discrete connection to the $(n-1)$th ball.

To see that $\Omega$ is connected: the distance between the mid-point of the $n$-th and $(n+1)$th ball is equal to
$$
\sqrt 2 h_{n}, 
$$
while the sum of their radii is
$$ 
\sigma (h_n + h_{n+1}) = \sigma\left( h_{n} + \frac 12 h_{n} \right)= \sigma \frac32 h_n > \sqrt 2 h_n.
$$

Comment: Wow. I have to think about it - but for the moment I can't find a logical mistake in your argumentation. Perhaps my statement is wrong. By the way, it should be $h_i$ in the sum.

Comment: isnt the diagonal in your set Omega? So, isnt there a connection between all the midpoints within the set?

Comment: @Bananach what is the diagonal of a set?

Comment: i meant the points $(x,x)$ in $R^2$. as far as I can tell, (x,x) is in the set daw defined as long as |x|<1 and thus all the midpoints of the balls are connected within the set.

Comment: @Bananach no - diagonal points are not connected because the connecting edge would have a length different then $h_n$. Its covered by a square grid.

Comment: okay, i thought the points of the grid were connected iff the line segment between them lies in the set.

Comment: Grid points are only connected by horizontal and vertical lines, no diagonals allowed.